# SharePoint 2010 not seeing Active Directory users

Tags: active-directory, user-accounts

This is a repost from here: https://serverfault.com/questions/380590/sharepoint-2010-not-seeing-active-directory-users Not sure how to migrate questions.

I'm pretty new to Active Directory and SharePoint but I was given to understand they are supposed to play well together.

Now I have successfully set up AD with multiple user accounts that work on any member computer. I have also successfully installed SharePoint 2010 Server on an AD machine. Both the AD server and SharePoint servers are on separate machines (VMs running on ESXi to be precise).

I can only log on with user accounts I create on the local server. Furthermore the user browser thing for adding users will only see local users.

I've followed the advice here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262350.aspx#section2 for Classic authentication and also NTLM claims based authentication but to no avail.

Is there something fundamental I am getting wrong here? I'd be really thankful for any help you can lend me; I've been googling and scratching my head for a couple of days now.

P

Comment: What kind of accounts are the service accounts? If local then they may not have permission to see the AD accounts. Have any AD users been granted access to SharePoint?

Comment: I'm not sure about the services. I installed it as an AC administrator.

I was thinking the AC users would be able to log in at the base level anyway. Would I need to add something like "NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users" to grant them permission?